# Container div is not expanding to full height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem where my container div is not fully expanding. The inner jumbotron div is overlapping it.

[image]

The orange is my jumbotron, while the green is my container. I need the jumbotron to stay inside the container.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
        <img src="../../images/logoonly.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre"
             class="img-responsive center-block">
    </div>
    <div id="custom-bootstrap-menu" class="navbar navbar-default " role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header"><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-menubuilder">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span><span class="icon-bar"></span><span
                        class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <!-- Navbar here-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Below code loops through the database and displays the result -->
    <?php
    if ($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM userinformation WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'")) {`enter code here`
        if ($count = $result->num_rows) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
                ?>
                <div class="jumbotron container-fluid">

                <!--Stuff here -->

                <?php
            }
            $result->free();
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Is there any dimensions on the jumbotron? Auto won't cut it in most circumstances, try `min-height: 80% to 100%` or `80vh to 100vh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding the following to your container css

```
overflow: auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

A 100% height setting only affects elements whose `position`is `absolute` or `fixed`. Since your "container" DIV seems to be the DIV containing everything else, "absolute" might make sense for that, plus `overflow: visible` for situations where the contents are higher than the screen/window - then it will scroll, and still show its background